React App throwing error - Something went wrong
I want to add Options value in the reportFields List dynamically using the categoryOptions state management which get the values from the getAllCategories function. I'm going somewhere wrong but don't know where.
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    const getAllCategories = () => {
      let url = `/category/list/active`;
      return http.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          const data = response.data;
          if (data.ok) {
            return data.data;
          } else {
            return [];
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          return [];
        });
    };
    
    interface Category {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    }
    
    const [categoryOptions, setCategoryOptions] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
      async function getCategoryOptions() {
        const categories = await getAllCategories();
        setCategoryOptions(
          categories.map((category: Category) => ({
            value: category.name,
            text: category.name,
          }))
        );
      }
      getCategoryOptions();
    }, []);
    
    
    export const reportFields = [
      {
        "headerName": "Category",
        "field": "category_id",
        "disabled":false,
        "default":true,
        "prefix": "",
        "suffix": "",
        "dbField": "final.category_name",
        "type": "string",
        "options": categoryOptions
      }
    ]


What is the error message?

The filename is report.ts
    at Object.V (react-dom.production.min.js:109:37)
    at c.useState (react.production.min.js:29:490)
    at eval (report.ts:35:64)
    at ./src/constants/report.ts```

I could get values from the url = /category/list/active which i tried in Postmaster.
I feel the error from the usage of useEffect and the async function getCategoryOptions.

Okay, so what does the full message say at reactjs.org?

It is saying --
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://react.dev/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.


You are breaking the rules of hooks. More specific: "Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.", at least by the looks of it you call useState and useEffect at the top level of the file they are in and not at the top level of a function component.

 const [categoryOptions, setCategoryOptions] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCategoryOptions() {
      const categories = await getAllCategories();
      setCategoryOptions(
        categories.map((category: Category) => ({
          value: category.name,
          text: category.name,
        }))
      );
    }
    getCategoryOptions();
  }, []);
  const reportFields = [
  {headerName: "Category", options: categoryOptions}
  ];
  return reportFields;
};
export const reportFields = ReportFieldsProvider();```

@PrasandKumar check and see if you imported reportFields and used it on top of a component or not.
